# 2D heatmap from x,y data / Octave

Tags: octave, heatmap

I am trying to create 2D heatmap from those two parameters:

```
diffQ = discharge(2:lgth) - discharge(1:lgth-1);
difft = time(2:lgth) - time(1:lgth-1);
```

My former colleague made code for just one parameter:

```
diff = discharge(2:lgth) - discharge(1:lgth-1);
bin = 1;
 idiff = int32(diff);
  mx = max(idiff);
  mn = min(idiff);
  msh = ones(((mx-mn)/bin)+2);

  for i = 1:lgth-2
    y = ((idiff(i)-mn)/bin)+1;
    x = (((idiff(i+1)-mn)/bin)+1);
    msh(x,y) = msh(x,y) + 1;
  end

  mshl = log(log(log(msh)+1)+1);
  newplot();
  surface(mshl,'EdgeColor','none');
  colormap(heatMapA);
```

but I can't figure out how to change plot creating for my case.

Thanks a lot
Kozina

Comment: it would help if you could provide a very minimal example of what your data looks like and what you'd like the heatmap to look like

Comment: The old data looked this way: [link](https://imgur.com/a/haEdpzl). 
Data: `period index,timestamp,phase,charge,voltage
0,159715617824,0.489245,-29.350319,-0.641761
0,159715620528,1.267890,-33.947356,-0.743124
0,159715624463,2.401014,37.837158,-0.844674
0,159715627890,3.387854,-29.703937,-0.947188
0,159715629803,3.938722,26.521372,-0.997187
0,159715631834,4.523570,-33.240120,-1.048134
0,159715636411,5.841564,28.996700,-1.206678
0,159715640327,6.969217,-28.289464,-1.315926
0,159715644576,8.192761,-31.472028,-1.428624` 


Time is `time= (period*20)+(phase*(20/360));`